# How do I ship a react component via script tag

Tags: reactjs

I want to ship a kind of chat/support box (built with React and MUI) through a single script tag on other peoples web sites like so:

```
<script src="myserver.com/support/123456789/app.js"></script>
```

This should insert a div and build the UI on their web site.

When developing the UI, I'm using whatever I'm given from npx create-react-app, i.e the `index.html`, with a `<div id="root"/>`, where my `<App>` gets inserted via `ReactDOM.render` in `index.js`.

However, I'm unable to figure out what exactly my **app.js** will be referring to, since I don't understand what is happening behind the scenes when `react-scripts` is running my application locally.

It hurts my ego to have to ask a question in this non-specific way, so please help me refine my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question with what seems to work so far.
I ended up re-creating parts of the create-react-app functionality using webpack. Perhaps I can make this work with "react-scripts build" once I understand how it works.

> index.html, this is an imaginary website that wants to use my script, so they include my code via a script-tag

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <script src="bundle.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> ./src/index.js, mounts or injects the app into the document from which it was loaded.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

// Dynamically create and append a DIV element to the bodytag.
const div = document.createElement("div")
div.id = "root";

// Then, render the app onto that div.    
document.body.appendChild(div);    
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,div);
```

> ./src/App.js, a dummy app that maintains a click-counter

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

// My React app
const App = () => {
   const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
   
   const handleClick = () => {
      setCount(count+1);
   }
   return(
      <div>
         <h1>#{count}</h1>
         <button onClick={handleClick}>ClickMe</button>
      </div>
      )
}
export default App;
```

> package.json, the only "real" dependencies are react and react-dom. The others are only needed for development.

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode=development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.64.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

> ./webpack.config.js, follow the dependencies from index.js and convert, transpile and do magic. Then, cobble everything together in one file called bundle.js. This is the file that gets included via scripts tag.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
   output:  {
      path:path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
      {
         test: /\.?js$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
            }
         }
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/i,
         use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
       },
      ]
   }
}
```